# Concurrent requests prevention

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I want to make some methods of my API to be locked (`HttpStatus.Conflict`) until another one with same params not finished (like ?id=1&key=sd6gd0f1g5ds16fh), like if bad user try to make 2+ same request at once, only one will be done.
My idea was to use `Semaphore`:

```
public class Lock : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed = false;

    private readonly Semaphore _semaphore;

    public bool IsLocked
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Lock(string name)
    {
        this.IsLocked = false;
        try
        {
            this._semaphore = Semaphore.OpenExisting(name);
            this._semaphore.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this._semaphore = new Semaphore(0, 1, name);
            this.IsLocked = true;
        }
    }

    ~Lock()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this._semaphore.Release();
                this._semaphore.Dispose();
            }

            this._disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
[ActionName("Ping")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Ping([FromUri]int? id = null, [FromUri]string key = null)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        //ProcessException is some wrap for api error answer
        throw new ProcessException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Service ID is required");
    }

    if (key == null)
    {
        throw new ProcessException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Service Key is required");
    }

    Lock serviceLock = new Lock("service." + id + "." + key);
    if (!serviceLock.IsLocked)
    {
        throw new ProcessException(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Other Service operation already in progress");
    }

    var service = Service.Get((int)id, key);
    if (service == null) // Right hereino
    {
        throw new ProcessException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Service ID and/or Key is invalid");
    }

    Service.Touch((int)id);

    serviceLock.Dispose();

    //JResponse is some wrap for Dictionary<string, object>
    return Ok(new JResponse(true));
}
```

But I'm pretty new to it and have some questions:

1. Am I going in true direction?
2. When I'm calling `Dispose`, `Semaphore` still exists on next request. What's wrong?
3. Will my class be disposed (and `Semaphore` released) on some exception? (Like we can see above, if `service == null`)

Comment: Do you have logged on users who you don't want concurrent requests from? Would you like to restrict concurrent requests from the same session? Or do you want to bottleneck all of your request from anywhere?

Comment: @NathanCooper There is no login. Auth by key on each request (/service/ping?id=1&key=1337). I want to restrict concurent execute of this ping by same id & key.

Comment: Okay here's a question, since GET operations have no side effects. Why do you care?

Comment: Request are by default single threaded.... what you are trying to do is restrict the amount of requests the same client can make. but why? Anyway you could simply have a static dictionary which keeps a record of how many request that client has made in the last min or whatever period. you would need to build a mechanism for clearing the failed responses i.e. dirty data left in the dictionary in case of exceptions/errors.

Comment: @NathanCooper, it was bad sample code. There is other methods that should write something to DB only once. But with concurent requests it can be written 2+ times, because firstly we SELECTing from DB, checking selected info and then UPDATEing.

Comment: @Seabizkit, I want to block concurent requests to prevent some important data be written to database 2+ more times. For example(!) we have money balance and we want to withdraw them, but with concurent request in same time it can be done twice (I know, bad example).

Comment: @ShamilYakupov if this is for something as important as banking stuff.... I would think about it more but for now you could defo have something in protected void Application_BeginRequest() { } and protected void Application-endrequest () {}, use a static dictionary add and entry for client on begin and remove on end. Then check to see if it already in dic on subsequent requests. Maybe record the time it was added to the dic aswell... so that you can use this for cleaning if needed.

Comment: @Seabizkit, not for banking, but it's still important to prevent concurent requests for some methods.

Answer (score -1):

This is not perfect and there is room for improvement but thought it might start you off an another direction or way to thinking.

Work your Semaphore stuff into locking the static dictionary

```
//ToDo: You would have to make this ThreadSafe
public static class Helper
{
    public static Dictionary<string,ClientDto> ClientDtos 
    = new Dictionary<string, ClientDto>();
}

public class ClientDto
{
    public int ClientKey { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

in your Global.asax add.
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    Helper.ClientDtos.Remove(SeesionId);
}

//if this is called twice by the same client and the request is 
//not finished processing the first request the second one will go into    
//RequestBeingHandled and just return preventing the code from preforming 
//the same action until the first/current is complete.

public IHttpActionResult Ping([FromUri]int? id = null, [FromUri]string key = null)
{
    if(RequestBeingHandled(id, key))
    {
        //
        Return .....
    }
    else 
    {
        //if not add 
        ClientDto client = new ClientDto();
        client.ClientKey = id;
        client.Key = key;
        client.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        Helper.ClientDtos.Add(SeesionId, client);
    }
    //call some code to do stuff...
}

private bool RequestBeingHandled(int id, string key)
{
    //ToDo: write this code.
    //check if its already in the dic
    return bool;
}
```

Comment: Isn't better to use named `Semaphore`'s like `"service.id.key"`?

Comment: @ShamilYakupov I don't see how your Lock class is globally accessible between request..... request = q     .e.g. q1, q2 q3 q4 all different clients all have **different** Lock classes.... now if they were all the same client, **same thing** all of them have different Lock class instances... so it doesn't make sense to me. Your current design 1 q = 1 thread = 1 Lock class, what you need is 1 q = 1 thread and a global which is in exist-stance between all q's. Hope that clears up that.

Comment: Isn't mutex working for whole app? I'm checking is it exists by name and if it is, just prevent this concurent action..

Comment: @ShamilYakupov lol you made me google mutex, mutex is a programming technique to archive what you are wanting... but you are not implementing it in such way... which is what im trying to point out to you. So currently your code will never work as the is no Global Class. Do some reading on how they archive mutex and then you will see.... that you will need to implement it around the dictionary which is what i have already say.

Comment: its weird someone down voted with comment "Concurrent requests prevention", which is not true!!! very odd its like they aren't reading or dont understand.